# setup problems with ANTLRworks 2.4.1 and 1.5.2

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

I haven't had any luck getting the ANTLRworks plug-ins to work. So this question is an attempt to update the ANTLRworks setup procedures and, as I say at the end, I'm willing to provide pull requests for the ANTLRworks website with updated notes.

Actually, ANTLR has several plug-ins for different IDE environments:

- ANTLRWorks 1.x. This is the original version of the IDE plug-in written by Jean Bovet and last updated on 10/8/13 for version 1.5.2.  It supports ANTLR v3.
- ANTLRWorks 2.x. This is a rewrite by Sam Harwell that targets NetBeans IDE. The documentation (http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53652/antlrworks-2) says that it supports both ANTLR v3 and ANTLR v4.
- IntelliJ plug-in by Terence Parr. This plug-in targets ANTLR v4.

Long story medium, I've tried both versions of ANLTLRworks but I haven't tried the IntelliJ plug-in because I still need ANTLR 3 compatibility.

**ANTLRworks 2.x**

For ANTLRworks 2, the trick is to install the plug-in (latest is 2.4.1) from within NetBeans IDE. It's also necessary to only use NetBeans IDE 8.0.1 because NetBeans 8.0 and 8.0.2 both have compatibility problems.

My problems with ANTLRworks 2.x are:

- I can't display diagrams at all.
- It seems to support only ANTLR v4 and I can't figure out how to create a v3 grammar. The docs say v3 and v4 support, but the plug-in description (Tools>Plug-ins, select Installed tab) says "The ANTLRWorks 2 core editor (ANTLR 4 and StringTemplate 4 support)".

**ANTLRworks 1.x**

So I moved on to ANTLRworks 1.x. For this I tried to install the plug-in in IntelliJ based on the notes provided on the website (http://www.antlr3.org/works/help/tutorial/intellij.html).

I'm using IntelliJ 14, so I'm being optimistic that the plug-in isn't out of date. The idea seems to be to build a plug-in module and I've reached the end of the notes when I get to these instructions:

> Use this configuration to run the plugin in another instance of IntelliJ. Once the other instance of IntelliJ is open, create a new project and then create a grammar file. Make sure to setup the javac path in the ANTLRWorks preferences (File > Settings > ANTLRWorks) to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_11\bin to avoid having issue launching the debugger from the plugin.

I'm not even sure what this means. I had been expecting to create some sort of jar file containing the plug-in, but this doesn't make any sense to me.

I've been keeping notes about about each of these procedures and I'm willing to create pull requests for either (or both) plug-in versions. But I'll need some help.

Comment: Err, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi Bart, I'm trying to get one or both of the ANTLRworks plugins to work. My guess is that the docs are out of whack. So I've been searching for a setup procedure for each of them. Maybe I should have broken the question into two questions...

Comment: I'll move this over to the mailing list.

Comment: Confirming that the ANTLRWorks 2 plugin is still broken/incompatible with NetBeans 8.0.2. Sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For NetBeans and the ANTLRWorks Plugin:

1. Install NetBeans 8.0.1
2. Tools > Plugins
3. Install ANTLRWorks

This doesn't work with 8.0.2, so make sure you get the older version.

https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can download the **antlrworks2** for Netbeans 8.2 from this repo: https://github.com/coreleon/antlrworks2

That guy build it appropriately and works EXCELLENT!

It seems that you can send him a request to build it for you for Netbeans 8.0.2.